# Django application not rendering static files

Tags: django

I have been trying to create a django application, but there is a problem with django rendering static files:

Here is my setting files static configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

I have placed all the static files in a static folder inside the location where manage.py resides.

Comment: Is this in development or production

Comment: this is in development!

Comment: Do you have DEBUG set to True?

Comment: Also, check your browser's dev tools. It could just be an incorrect path.

Answer (score 1):

Here you defined an STATIC_ROOT, so you after placing your static files and on each change of your css or js files you need to run

`python manage.py collectstatic`

This command will gather all static files into the defined dictionary, but this is done after the completion of development. So instead of that you can use STATICFILES_DIRS during development,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

which will automatically find the static files during your development period.

Also make sure you have staticfiles in installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles', # it's is used for static files
]
```

In your template you can load static files like

```
{% load staticfiles %}  # register static tag
<link ref="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
```

urls.py (main project's urls.py)

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```